# Assigning multiple css classes with a single name

Tags: css

*Note: It appears that I was ignorant of the proper use of CSS when I posted this question. Nevertheless I'm not deleting the question in case the display of my ignorance helps somebody else get on the right track.*

I want to apply a bunch of classes to a single CSS container using just one class name. For example I might want to style something like a div tag with a bunch of typical w3 classes like this

```
<DIV CLASS="w3-margin w3-padding w3-green">
```

I'd like to combine "w3-margin w3-padding w3-green" into a single class name, like perhaps `my-typical-classes` so I can just do this

```
<DIV CLASS="my-typical-classes">
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't combine multiple CSS classes into a single CSS class wuthout manually combining/adding each classes' properties/content into that single class. There's no such feature and it's quite illogical. CSS classes are mainly serve reusability purpose.

Comment: What's illogical @M. Çağlar TUFAN?  That no such feature exists? I'd certainly agree. Seems like a totally obvious thing to want to do. I can't believe it's not possible.  If you think it's illogical, please explain.

Comment: @ChrisNadovich it's not totally illogical but you can already combine classes just by using them in your element's class property like `<div class"w3-margin w3-padding ...">` and the browser will figure out which properties of these classes are overlapping and will find and apply the properties of classes that have highest precedence over others. That's exactly what you need but instead of typing a single class for multiple classes, you need to type them separately. When you combine multiple classes into one, you are kind of shadowing the purpose of CSS classes.

Comment: I want to apply the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). I use this same long list of classes in many places. If I want to change the list, I have to go to those many places and change it in each location. But if I can combine those names into a single name -- like a subroutine or a parent class -- I only have one place to change it.  Is there an alternative approach that achieves the same goal?

Comment: @ChrisNadovich well, you are wrong. If there were such feature in HTML or CSS, could be useful for such cases. You can avcomplish the same using JavaScript but you will need to write a code which will add multiple classes to classList of that element that has the specified class name. But that's not an efficient way. I think you can use bundling libraries/tools such as webpack to somehow get that feature but that's not a default feature they support. So in the end you will need to write something that will compile these class changes for you.

Comment: What exactly am I wrong about? I'm so lucky to have you correct me. Please educate me. I'm just trying to use the W3 CSS framework to style my pages. I want to use groups of those styles efficiently to create a theme that repeats in many places without violating the DRY principle. I thought this would ease maintenance. I guess I'm wrong in wanting to do this.  I'll just paste the same class list in the many places and not worry about it any more. Thank you for explaining what is not possible.